# R/Shiny - can't see the pie chart with rCharts

Tags: r, charts, shiny, pie-chart, rcharts

I am just starting using Shiny and i can't understand why I can't see my pie chart.
I have done the following :

in Server.R

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
require('rCharts')
```

....

```
output$plot5 <- renderChart({
Q<-read.csv("C:/data/GEMT2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";",dec=",")
Q[,3] <- as.character(Q[,3])
Q[,4] <- as.numeric(Q[,4])

df <- data.frame(ckey = Q[,3], value = Q[,4],stringsAsFactors=F)

df$fkey <- factor(df$ckey,levels=Q[,3])

hPlot(x = "fkey", y = "value", data = df, type = "pie",title="By Order (fkey)")
})
```

in ui.R

```
box(showOutput("plot5", "polycharts")
   )
```

I know the problem in not on my CSV file because when i use the "normal" shiny plot fonction, the chart appears. You can see this case just below

Server.r

```
output$plot5 <- renderPlot({
P<-read.csv("C:/data/GEMT2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";",dec=",")
P[,3] <- as.character(P[,3])
P[,4] <- as.numeric(P[,4])

pie(P[,4],labels = P[,3])
```

})

Then in ui.R

```
plotOutput("plot2", height = 200)
```

In GEMT2.csv, i have :

RG1 RG2 RO1 RO2

Europe  68,6    Part Etat   16,8

US  16,4    Part IG     32,6

Japon   0,5 Part HY 23,1

EM  3,8 NR  0,3

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Can you upload `GEMT2.csv` somewhere online?

Comment: No, the problem in not on GEMT2.csv because i can plop with the classical shiny fonction

Comment: in order to help you we need all the variables, your data is one of them

Comment: I have edited my post for you to see it is not the problem

Comment: Again, you are not showing the contents of your `.csv` file. If you dont want to then use some dummy data to create a reproducible example

Comment: I have edited, so you can see my CSV file